# Prevent interruption of tabbing between Leaflet markers

Tags: leaflet, keyboard, google-maps-markers, mouse

I can tab with the keyboard between markers in my Leaflet map in Chrome and it nicely displays a rectangle around the selected marker and displays its tooltip. If I zoom or pan the map with the mouse, however, the next tab reverts to the first marker defined in my map. I can sometimes prevent this by keeping the mouse over the selected marker while panning or zooming, but want to prevent loss of tab position in all cases.

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-keyboard